# How to center a rotated rectangle at its top left original location

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

*A note: The original post were deleted with its user, and as I found it could be useful, I reposted it.*

---

The rectangle should be rotated -90deg and be centered vertical in the left side of the screen. As you can see in the picture below.

If possible, only HTML and CSS should be used.

[image: How it should look]

The problem is, to first rotate the element, which makes it more difficult to center it.

Stack snippet

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body>div {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
  transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To better control the rotation, and more easily both left align and center it vertically, use both the [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) and [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform).

First make its left/top corner as the center of the rotation by adding `transform-origin: left top;` to the `div`.

Second, by combine `rotate` and `translate`, move it half of its own width to the left (`translateX(-50%)`), and then rotate it 90 degrees counterclockwise `rotate(-90.0deg)`.

*Note 1; When using more than one [`<transform-function>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#%3Ctransform-function%3E) value, they execute from right to left, which in below sample mean it starts with `translateX`.*

*Note 2; I temporary removed the prefixed properties, so you need to add them back.*

Stack snippet

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #ccc;
 }

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body>div {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
  transform-origin: left top;
  transform: rotate(-90.0deg) translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
```

---

Update after a comment.

<strike>Here is 4 fiddles, showing 4 steps, that hopefully make it more clear how this works:</strike>

[Step 1](https://jsfiddle.net/7uLar0c2/2/) - [Step 2](https://jsfiddle.net/7uLar0c2/3/) - [Step 3](https://jsfiddle.net/7uLar0c2/4/) - [Step 4](https://jsfiddle.net/7uLar0c2/5/)

Here is an animation, showing how it moves, and hopefully make it more clear how this works:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 }

.faked-body div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
  transform-origin: left top;    /*  the rotation center is moved to black circle  */
  transform: rotate(0)
             translateX(0);
  animation: the-div 3s 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes the-div {
  0%   { transform: rotate(0)
                    translateX(0);
  }
  50%  { transform: rotate(0)
                    translateX(-50%);  /*  move to left */
  }
  100% { transform: rotate(-90deg)     /*  rotate 90 degree */
                    translateX(-50%);
  }
}


/*  styling/info for this demo  */
.faked-body div::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  animation: the-spot 1.5s 1s forwards;
}
.faked-body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 60px;
  width: 440px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.faked-body::before {
  content: 'The gray area represents the body so we can see how the "Lorem Ipsum" element moves';
  color: #666;
}
.faked-body::after {
  content: 'The black spot show where the rotation center is';
  color: #222;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; left: 0;
}
@keyframes the-spot {
  0%   { left: 0;
  }
  100% { left: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="faked-body">
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
We can use the 'text-orientation' property instead of 'rotate'.
I tried the below code and it worked for me.
 html,
 body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        align-content: center;
      }
body > div {
        background-color: #ff0000;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 10px;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        writing-mode: vertical-rl;
        text-orientation: upright;
      }
```

Create another parent div to 'Lorem Ipsum' and apply  "display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            align-content: center;" properties to the parent div to avoid giving flex to 'body' tag.
Hope it helps.

Comment: The letters are suppose to be rotated as well. Also note, the browser support on these is quite low

Answer (score -1):

Understood. Please try the below css, it may solve your issue.

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
div {
  margin: auto auto auto 10;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
    transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
    padding: 10px;
}
```

FYI: I tested this on chrome and safari and working.